# Representing Grammars in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, elisp, grammar

Does anybody know of a project that uses Emacs-Lisp or Common-Lisp to formally encode grammars of programming languages? My special requirement is that I plan to use the representation to optionally encode translations between grammar rules.

Comment: https://www.cliki.net/text

Comment: I'd suggest to ask on reddit /r/lisp

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Alexa](https://github.com/quil-lang/alexa) and [cl-yacc](https://github.com/jech/cl-yacc) in Common Lisp.

Ill answer this by using some examples from a compiler I wrote.

suppose you want to write a grammar for python. you would do this:

define lexer:

```
(deftype token ()
  `(cons type val))

(defun tok (type &optional val)
  (cons type val))

(alexa:define-string-lexer python-lexer
    "Make a lexical analyzer for Python expressions."
  ((:num "\\d+")
   (:name "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*"))
  ("and"      (return (tok :boolop (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("or"       (return (tok :boolop (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("not"      (return (tok :unaryop  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\("      (return (tok :left-paren)))
  ("\\)"      (return (tok :right-paren)))
  ("\\+"      (return (tok :plus (intern $@ 'keyword))))
  ("\\-"      (return (tok :minus (intern $@ 'keyword))))
  ("\\=="     (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\!="     (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\<"      (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\<="     (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\>"      (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\>="     (return (tok :cmp  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("\\="      (return (tok :assignment)))
  ("True"     (return (tok :bool  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("False"    (return (tok :bool  (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("if"       (return (tok :if    (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("else"     (return (tok :else (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("while"    (return (tok :while (intern (string-upcase $@) 'keyword))))
  ("print"    (return (tok :print (intern (string-upcase $@) "ZETTA-VAR"))))
  ("fun"      (return (tok :fun (intern (string-upcase $@) "ZETTA-VAR"))))
  ("\\:"      (return (tok :colon)))
  ("{{NAME}}" (return (tok :name (intern (string-upcase $@) "ZETTA-VAR"))))
  ("{{NUM}}"  (return (tok :constant (parse-integer $@))))
  ("\\s+"    nil))

(defun token-generator (toks)
  (lambda ()
    (if (null toks)
    (values nil nil)
    (let ((tok (pop toks)))
      (values (token-type tok)
          (token-value tok))))))

(defun token-type (tok)
  (car tok))

(defun token-value (tok)
  (cdr tok))

(defun lex-line (string)
  (loop :with lexer := (python-lexer string)
    :for tok := (funcall lexer)
    :while tok
    :collect tok))
```

and the parser you would write like this:

```
(define-parser *python-grammar*
    (:start-symbol module)
  (:terminals (:boolop :unaryop :cmp :bool :assignment :if :else :while :colon :name :constant :right-paren :left-paren :print :plus :minus :fun))
  (module
   (statements #'build-module))
  (statements
   statement
   exp
   (statement statements)
   (exp statements))
  (statement
   (:print :left-paren :right-paren)
   (:print :left-paren exp :right-paren #'build-print)
   function
   exp
   assignment
   (statements :while exp :colon statements #'build-while)
   (:if exp :colon statements :else :colon statements #'build-if))
  (function
   (:fun variable :left-paren args :right-paren :colon statements #'build-function))
  (exp
   variable
   int
   (:minus exp #'build-neg-num)
   (exp :plus exp #'build-addition)
   (exp :minus exp #'build-sub)
   (:bool #'build-bool)
   (exp :boolop exp #'build-bool-op)
   (:unaryop exp #'build-unaryop)
   (exp :cmp exp #'build-cmp))
  (args
   variable
   (variable args))
  (variable
   (:name #'build-variable))
  (assignment
   (:name :assignment exp #'build-assignment))
  (int
   (:constant #'build-int))))
```

If you know how to write a grammar then writing the parser is straightforward. The only tricky part is the functions you see by the rules. these functions allow you to construct your ast; for example, consider the function `build-function`:

```
(defun build-function (fun-tok var lparen-tok args r-paren colon-tok statements)
  (declare (ignore fun-tok lparen-tok r-paren colon-tok))
  (make-py-function :name var
            :args args
            :statements statements))
```

where `make-py-function` is a structure ie:

```
(defstruct py-function name args statements)
```

so when the parser calls this functions it constructs a parser node using a the given structure.